# The little envelope is gone

Tags: support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where has the enveloppe gone to?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1766/where-has-the-enveloppe-gone-to)

So, the *Designers* have removed the little envelope that sat on the top of the site pages, and replaced with this a little bit more of ajaxy 2.0ness which shows up a little dialog box which displays information I have never had any use for. (How many times are you going to have any use for the 'priviledges' link offered there?!)

Can anyone see where they hid the useful bit of information (recent votes to one's questions/answers) that was linked to by the little envelope?

Comment: I find closure of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82692/why-cant-you-roll-out-new-features-the-way-everybody-else-does most characteristic.

Comment: I believe it is under users/recent/

Comment: @Moron: No one says that the page is gone. Just the link to it.

Comment: @Asaf: I don't understand what you mean by that. I was just stating where it is. I never checked to see where that page was, when the envelope was there. Perhaps there are other people who didn't bother to check, just like me and might help them.

Comment: +1 @Moron: since your comment technically does answer the question posed ("Where they hid the useful bit of information...") maybe you should put that as an answer in one of the two threads?

Comment: @Willie: Added it to the other answer. I think we should just close this as a dupe.

Comment: I find it sort of peculiar that the question that this was marked a duplicate of is deleted...